GeoNetwork : Difficulties for integrating/linking WFS/WMS geoservices into metadata record (slowness)
With GeoNetwork 4.2.3, I'm facing difficulties regarding one record. I don't notice this problem for all records, just this one. The problem is for integrating/linking WFS/WMS within the metadata record. I succeed without problem in loading the data (postgis layer) into QGIS (WFS/WMS).For information, the WFS/WMS geoservices are published using GeoServer.
So when editing the metadata record and trying to link/integrate the WMS/WFS the page becomes really slow :


And I assume that the geoservices are not functional if integrated into the record. I tried to reindexed this record but that didn't change anything.
Moreover, When I authenticate (admin) on the catalog, I can't access the record editing interface. There is a message saying 'An error occurred while calling the service':

For information, there are several spatial reference systems : for the PostGIS layer (EPSG:2154 - RGF93 v1 / Lambert-93 - Projected), the WMS (not projected in EPSG:4326 - WGS 84) and WFS (not projected in EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator).
If needed, I can share catalina.out log file.
